# Is it safe to attempt (and fail) to write to a const on an STM32?

Tags: visual-c++, embedded, stm32

So, we are experimenting with an approach to perform some matrix math.  This is embedded, so memory is limited, and we will have large matrices so it helps us to keep some of them stored in flash rather than RAM.

I've written a matrix structure, two arrays (one const/flash and the other RAM), and a "modify" and "get" function.  One matrix, I initialize to the RAM data, and the other matrix I initialize to the flash data, using a cast from const *f32 to *f32.

What I find is that when I run this code on my STM32 embedded processor, the RAM matrix is modifiable, and the matrix pointing to the flash data simply doesn't change (the set to 12.0 doesn't "take", the value remains 2.0).

(before change) a=2, b=2, (after change) c=2, d=12

This is acceptable behavior, by design we will not attempt to modify matrices of flash data, but if we make a mistake we don't want it to crash.

If I run the same code on my windows machine with Visual C++, however, I get an "access violation" when I attempt to run the code below, when I try to modify the const array to 12.0.

This is not surprising that Windows would object, but I'd like to understand the difference in behavior better.  This seems related to CPU architecture.  Is it safe, on our STM32, to let the code attempt to write to a const array and let it have no effect?  Or are there side effects, or reasons to avoid this?

```
static const f32 constarray[9] = {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3};
static f32 ramarray[9] = {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3};

typedef struct {
     u16 rows;
     u16 cols;
     f32 * mat;
} matrix_versatile;

void modify_versatile_matrix(matrix_versatile * m, uint16_t r, uint16_t c, double new_value)
{
    m->mat[r * m->cols + c] = new_value;    
}

double get_versatile_matrix_value(matrix_versatile * m, uint16_t r, uint16_t c)
{
    return m->mat[r * m->cols + c];
}

double a;
double b;
double c;
double d;

int main(void)
{
    matrix_versatile matrix_with_const_data;
    matrix_versatile matrix_with_ram_data;

    matrix_with_const_data.cols = 3;
    matrix_with_const_data.rows = 3;
    matrix_with_const_data.mat = (f32 *) constarray;

    matrix_with_ram_data.cols = 3;
    matrix_with_ram_data.rows = 3;
    matrix_with_ram_data.mat = ramarray;

    a = get_versatile_matrix_value(&matrix_with_const_data, 1, 1);
    b = get_versatile_matrix_value(&matrix_with_ram_data, 1, 1);
    modify_versatile_matrix(&matrix_with_const_data, 1, 1, 12.0);
    modify_versatile_matrix(&matrix_with_ram_data, 1, 1, 12.0);
    c = get_versatile_matrix_value(&matrix_with_const_data, 1, 1);
    d = get_versatile_matrix_value(&matrix_with_ram_data, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

> but if we make a mistake we don't want it to crash.

Attempting to write to ROM will not in itself cause a crash, but the code attempting to write it is *by definition* buggy and may crash in any case, and will certainly not behave as intended.

It is almost entirely wrong thinking; if you have a bug, you *really* want it to crash during development, and not after deployment.  If it silently does the wrong thing, you may never notice the bug, or the crash might occur somewhere other than in proximity of the bug, so be very hard to find.

Architectures an MMU or MPU may issue an exception if you attempt to write to memory marked as read-only.  That is what is happening in Windows.  In that case it can be a useful debug aid given an exception handler that reports such errors by some means.  In this case the error is reported exactly when it occurs, rather than crashing some time later when some invalid data is accessed or incorrect result acted upon.

Some, but mot all STM32 parts include the MPU ([application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/bc/2d/f7/bd/fb/3f/48/47/DM00272912/files/DM00272912.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00272912.pdf))

Comment: Got it.  Yes, at development time we will check and double check that we are never attempting to modify a FLASH-based matrix.  But I'm curious, you say our STM32 "may crash in any case"... can you expand on that, what might happen?

Comment: In short, I guess I assumed that this was a *feature*, that the CPU was smart enough to realize that it was modifying FLASH and it would noop instead.  But this is speculation.  What is really happening, and how would it fail?

Comment: Oh, and further on the development philosophy I think we will add a boolean to our matrix structure to indicate RW or RO, for further protection, so that even in the event of a mixup we do not attempt to write to FLASH and rely on this "noop" behavior.  So mostly at this point I'm just curious: why does it have no effect, is this a feature, can we count on it, or is this behavior undefined, indeterminate, and could bite us?  And if it bites us, how?

Comment: @Chris you can write a function that checks the address against the memory map of the controller and the board (if there is external memory).

Comment: @Chris The behaviour is determinate, *documented*, so you can count on it as a feature. The effect of writing a known value to a known address is completely predictable. RAM: value changes, FLASH: no change and status bit is set, memory mapped register: see the Reference Manual, unmapped area: Bus Fault. Problems start to happen when the address or the value is not predictable.

Comment: @Chris how exactly it would bite you depends on the compiler and the program logic. Both of them expect that if a value is put in an array element, it stays there. If the memory is not writable, it will apparently revert back to the old value *some time after the assignment*.

Comment: @Chris re first comment, I simply meant the code is incorrect, and incorrect code behaves incorrectly including the possibility of a crash.  Besides "crash" is a very ill-defined term that could cover a wide range of behavior.  The point is it does not matter whether the processor crashes or not, it will not perform its task if the code is doing unexpected things - if you write to ROM, that is in itself benign, but presumably it was intended to do something else, which is not being done.

Comment: @Chris re second comment; the core does not know that the memory is not writable (and with flash, it can be both ROM or writable); it simply asserts the address and data bus and the write signal, and that action has no effect on the ROM.  It is a _feature_ of the memory type, not of the processor.  You can "rely" on it not to modify the memory, no more.

Comment: @chris Defensive code is one thing, but your approach makes no sense - you are writing _more_software to check for software errors.  What makes you think that if you expect to write broken software, writing yet more software will detect it!?  A system of asserts on results or reconditions and unit testing is a more robust approach.  You are proposing writing code to detect one specific type of code error; what about all the more likely errors.  Moreover the error you have exemplified is down to poor coding practice - casting away a const. If you don't do that the compiler will catch it.

Comment: @berendi said "_FLASH: no change and status bit is set,_" - What status bit?  There are status bits in the flash controller, but those are in play only when flash programming.  This question appears to be about attempting to write to ROM or `const` data more generically, not a failed attempt at a deliberate write.

Comment: @Clifford Bit 7 of `FLASH->SR` on an STM32F4, don't know about other series. From the RM: *Bit 7 PGSERR: Programming sequence error Set by hardware when a write access to the Flash memory is performed by the code while the control register has not been correctly configured.* It is set when one attempts to write dereferencing a pointer that points to the flash.

Comment: @berendi You are replying to my comment but addressing Chris.  Moreover I deleted the comment you are referring to; I read your answer and realised what you are talking about, but think you have entirely missed the point of the question

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on the series (STM32F1, STM32F4, STM32L1 etc), as they have somewhat different flash controllers.

I've once made the same mistake on an STM32F429, and investigated a bit, so I can tell what would happen on an STM32F4.

*Probably* nothing.

The flash is by default protected, in order to be somewhat resilient to those kind of programming errors. In order to modify the flash, one has to write certain values to the `FLASH->KEYR` register. If the wrong value is written, then the flash will be locked until reset, so nothing really bad can happen unless the program writes 64 bits of correct values. No unexpected interrupts can happen, because the interrupt enable bit is protected by this key too. The attempt will set some error bits in `FLASH->SR`, so a program can check it and warn the user (preferably the tester).

However if there is some code there (e.g. a bootloader, or logging something into flash) that is *supposed* to write something in the flash, i.e. it unlocks the flash with the correct keys, then *bad things* can happen.

If the flash is left unlocked after a preceding write operation, then writing to a previously programmed area will change bits from `1` to `0`, but not from `0` to `1`. It means that the flash will contain the bitwise `AND` of the old and the newly written value.

If the failed write attempt occurs first, and unlocked afterwards, then no legitimate write or erase operation would succeed unless the status bits are properly cleared first.

If the intended and unintended accesses occur interleaved, e.g. in interrupt handlers, then all bets are off.

---

Even if the values are in immutable flash memory, there can still be unexpected result. Consider this code

```
int foo(int *array) {
  array[0] = 1;
  array[1] = 3;
  array[2] = 5;
  return array[0];
}
```

An optimizing compiler might recognize that the return value should always be `1`, and emit code to that effect. Or it might not, and reload `array[0]` from wherever it is stored, possibly a different value from flash. It may behave differently in debug and release builds, or when the function is called from different places, as it might be inlined differently.

---

If the pointer points to an unmapped area, neither RAM nor FLASH nor some memory mapped register, then a a fault *will* occur, and as the default fault handlers contain just an infinite loop, the program will hang unless it has a fault handler installed that can deal with the situation. Needless to say, overwriting random RAM areas or registers can result in barely predictable behaviour.

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried your code on actual hardware. When I ran it verbatim, the compiler (`gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update -O3 -lto`) optimized away everything, since the variables were not used afterwards. Marking `a, b, c, d` as `volatile` resulted in `c=2` and `d=12`, it was still considering the first array `const`, and no accesses to the arrays were generated. `constarray` did not show up in the map file at all, the linker had eliminated it completely.

So I've tried a few things one at a time to force the optimizer to generate code that would actually access the arrays.

- Disablig optimization (`-O0`)
- Making all variables `volatile`
- Inserting a couple of compile-time memory barriers (`asm volatile("":::"memory");`
- Doing some complex calculations in the middle

Any of these has produced varying effects on different MCUs, but they were always consistent on a single platform.

- **`STM32F103`**: Hard Fault. Only halfword (16 bit) write accesses are allowed to the flash, 8 or 32 bits always result in a fault. When I've changed the data types to `short`, the code ran, of course without any effect on the flash.
- **`STM32F417`**: Code runs, with no effects on the flash contents, but bits 6 and 7, `PGPERR` and `PGSERR` in `FLASH->SR` were set a few cycles after the first write attempt to `constarray`.
- **`STM32L151`**: Code runs, with no effects on the flash controller status.

Comment: The question appears to be about write access to a read-only address rather then more specifically about failure to write to flash memory because it is explicitly write-protected.  Write protection is only relevant when _programming_ flash; when not in programming mode, the access has no effect at all, unless the part has an MPU and the region is marked read-only.  The title and code example refer to `const` rather then specifically flash memory an flash programming.

Comment: @Clifford `const` arrays are placed in the flash by the linker, unless one uses some really weird linker script or startup code. If the `const` qualifier is lost when passing the array address to a function that expects a non-const pointer parameter, and attempts to write to an array element, then it will try to write a value to an address in flash. Of course the flash contents would be left unchanged, but the flash controller sees it as a *failed programming attempt*, and sets the error flag in its status register.

Comment: @Clifford It has once got me wondering why my code that deliberately writes the flash stops working when a certain unrelated function is invoked. Turned out the unrelated function had the same kind of bug as the code example in the question. Flash programming started to work when I've cleared `FLASH->SR`, and monitoring the status register has helped me to find the real bug.

Comment: I disagree, there is no attempt to program the flash memory at runtime in the question.  It is an important consideration if you _are_ programming flash at runtime (a practice that has particular issues in STM32 in any case), but it clearly does not relate to this question.

Comment: @Clifford I've tried it on actual hardware, see my updated answer. The flash controller does not really care what the programmer was *attempting* to do, it sets the flags on write accesses. Or raises a fault.

Comment: it really comes down to what he means by "safe" perhaps.  The premise is nonsense, since if the access is occurring unexpectedly, it is not possible to predict the effect of such a bug.